# Generic Repository Includes and Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

I have created a generic Repository.  At the moment I have a StaffRepository that inherits from my generic one (Repository).
This works well, as my generic Repository has my CRUD operations and allows me to use these in my service aswell as the methods in my StaffRepository which does additional filtering on the context and adds includes.
However, I need to create a Repository for each entity, (Most filter by ClientId and the primary key). 
Is there a way I can use a generic approach for both the filtering and applying the includes?
Also am I applying the right approach here? Thanks for your help.

Example StaffRepository:

```
 public class StaffRepository : Repository<Staff>
{
    public StaffRepository(ApplicationDbContext _context) : base(_context)
    {
    }

    public async Task<List<Staff>> GetAsync(int clientId)
    {
        return await _context.Staff
            .Include(s => s.Person)
            .Include(u => u.Person.User)
            .Include(p => p.Photograph)
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Staff> GetByIdAsync(int clientId, int staffId)
    {
        return await _context.Staff
            .Include(s => s.Person)
            .Include(u => u.Person.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ClientId == clientId && x.StaffId == staffId);
    }
}
```

My Generic Repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    internal readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public async Task<T> FindAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        await _context.Set<T>().AddRangeAsync(entities);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
    {
        if (_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Expression<Func< allows you to inject a parameter to the (INCLUDE) aspect of your query expression. Predicate builder is your friend here : http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Programmer I will take a look, are you able to give me an example based on the above please?

Comment: Are you sure you want more generic? You seem to be on the right track as far as the repository pattern goes. Your other repositories might use different includes, or filter fields, or are there commonalities in there? Usually you don't go full generic from the get go in general as you first need to identify the commonalities of where generics can be used.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Thanks for your advice, it makes sense.  I do have some additional filtering logic that is not always generic, so I think continuing my approach with separate repositories is best practice here, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user2270653 It is best practice until it isn't, I suppose that's the best advice I can give. You need your codebase to mature before you can identify commonalities that really take advantage of generic methods. It is good that you are thinking about this right away but usually comes back to bite you if you blindly go wild with generics. Let it be a refactoring exercise some time down the line when there is an obvious need for generics.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is using expressions like you can see on my GetAsync method below:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal DbContext dbContext;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.dbContext = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "",
            int first = 0, int offset = 0)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (offset > 0)
            {
                query = query.Skip(offset);
            }
            if (first > 0)
            {
                query = query.Take(first);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return await query.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I just included my repository with the GetAsync method and I will recommend you using the UnityOfWork pattern so you can have your instances of this repository (for each entity) on a centralized place like:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private GenericRepository<YourEntity> yourRepository;

        private DbContext context;

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public GenericRepository<YourEntity> YourRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.yourRepository== null)
                {
                    this.yourRepository= new GenericRepository<YourEntity>(context);
                }
                return yourRepository;
            }
        }
}
```

Then this is just an example how to instantiate this:

```
await unitOfWork.YourRepository.GetAsync(filter: w => w.OtherKeyNavigation.Id == 123456, includeProperties: "OtherKeyNavigation", first: 20, offset: 0);
```

Note: I'm not including all the code from neither the Repository nor the UnityOfWork because is not part of this question.
Thanks